# Tomahawk JSF 1.2 file upload is not working in JBoss 7.3 EAP while it worked fine in JBoss 6

Tags: jsf, jboss7.x, jsf-1.2, tomahawk

Recently we have upgraded JBoss 6 tp 7.3 EAP servert and Java 6 to Java 8 version still jsf is configured to version 1.2 only

Somehow file upload is not working in Jboss 7.3 EAP and the same is worked in Jboss 6. Then backed UploadedFile object is not binding to selected file from ui always it's null. All other input fields binding properly. Tried with valuchangelistener, tried by upgrading tomahawk version from 1.1.8 to 1.1.14.

Not able to understand where would be the problem, Pls let me know if you require more details

Comment: The Tomahawk JSF 1.2 file upload is parsed by a servlet filter. Doublecheck the servlet filter configuration (especially the ordering of them and any kind of filter which could possibly block/change the request, e.g. URL rewriting or authentication). A definitive answer cannot be given because this debugging information is missing in the question. In fact, you need to debug yourself first and then describe the actual technical problem and only then we can provide a solution to that (if you cannot already see it yourself). Stack Overflow is not exactly a remote debugging service.